# = operator throwing exception

Tags: java, sorting

I am a very novie Java programmer.I am trying to sort an array of strings using compareTo function.But in my code the '=' operator is causing problem in the code.Can someone help me? Thanks

```
public class StringSort 
{
    static String arr[]= ("Now","My","There","When");
        public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<arr.length;j++)
            {
                if(arr[i].compareTo(arr[j])<0)
                {
                    String t=arr[j];
                    arr[j]=arr[i];
                    arr[i]=t;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Surely we can guess about what exactly the problem is, and where it happens... in this case it happened to be easy. In general it makes everyone's life easier though if you explicitly describe what exception / error occurred, on which line. And if it's a runtime error, you should also describe the input and output data if applicable.

Comment: Next time when asking a question please state at what line number the error occurred to make it easier for us to answer. In this question there are 6 '=' operators.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use braces instead of paratheses around the array initializer.

```
 static String arr[]= {"Now","My","There","When"};
```

Answer (score 4):

`static String arr[]= new String[]{"Now","My","There","When"};`

Answer (score 1):

When declaring an array outright, with items inside, you use curly braces.

```
static String arr[]= {"Now","My","There","When"};
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to make it private and final if you can. Also use Java array notation instead f C notation.

```
private final static String[] arr = {"Now","My","There","When"};
```

Its also best to limit the scope of a field to where it is lives (i.e. created, used and discarded). i.e. its only used in one method so you can define it there.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arr = "Now,My,There,When".split(",");
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

Comment: You also need to think of how the method may be used. Such as consider frequency of calls and the cost of creating the field value. In this case, as it is `main` that's only once but in a real class and method it often is still useful to statically initialize the field in the class (not method) even if the scope is just the method.